# How to aggregate records in django based on multiple criteria

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say, I have following models in my Django app.

```
class EventGroup
    name = models.CharField()

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(EventGroup)

class Severity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(EventGroup)

class LogEntry(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
    severity = models.ForeignKey('Severity')
```

What is the optimal way to find latest log entries of each severity for each event in a group? That is, if I have an event group with some severities and some events related to it, I would expect to get a list of latest log entries for each combination of severity and event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be something along the lines of:

```
groups = EventGroup.objects.all()
for group in groups:
    for event in group.event_set.all():
        LogEntry.objects.filter(event = event).latest('timestamp')
```

This will hit the database multiple times.

Another way would be to start with the `LogEntry` model. This approach requires fewer queries.

```
groups = EventGroup.objects.all()
for group in groups:
    LogEntry.objects.select_related().filter(event__group = group).latest('timestamp')
```

<strike>Warning: I haven't tested this code.</strike> This is working for me.

Comment: Sorry, but I have missed a bit of structure when describing the models (see the edited code). I tried to do the same as you suggested with nested loops, but it seems slow. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Mad Wombat: how about the second option, where you start from the `LogEntry`? Was that any better?

Comment: Not really. Seems like the nested loops kill the performance, since even in the second version of the code the main query runs for every iteration. I am trying to figure out either a functional approach to this or use Django QuerySet APIs in some creative way.

Comment: And the second version of the code only gives me one entry per group, where it should give me one entry per event in a group

Comment: @Mad Wombat: Are you open to falling back to raw SQL?